# OkHttp get current URL location

Tags: java, url, okhttp

I want  to retrieve some #hash variable that will be added to page by server to which I am making call, how to do this? I tried Location header but it is null

Answer (score 4):

Found solution 
response.networkResponse().request().urlString(); shold give you last url to which client was redirected

Comment: I don't think you want `networkResponse()` in there, though; do you?

Comment: @EricCochran Yes you are right, I though that just request() will return request initiated by app rather than last request initiated by client, thanks.

Comment: Yep, response.request() is the Request after all redirects and such. (If you happen to need the original Request, you'd probably need to pick it out of the Call.)